# How to have some code run for only the first time, the Azure function runs?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-functions, dotnet-httpclient

I'm writing an azure function to request a token from a token service. Specifically a web chat token for a chatbot, for this I need to attach a bearer token to the request and have only one httpClient for all the requests.

I just want to run the following line once:
`httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);`. The first time the function is ever called, otherwise an error saying that the authorization header already exists occurs.

My current workaround is having another static boolean value, that is checked after running the first time and updated afterwards.

Here is the code for the azure function below.

```cs
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


private static string secret = "";

private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
private static bool runOnce = true;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    if (runOnce){
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + secret);
        runOnce = false;
    }

    // Token request
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://webchat.botframework.com/api/tokens");
    var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var obj = new ReturnObject();
    obj.Token = contents;

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

    return new OkObjectResult(json);
}

public class ReturnObject
{
    public string Token {get; set;}
}
```

It seems to work right now, but there should be a more proper way to do this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [Static Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors), which "is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced."

eg:

```
class Globals
{
    public readonly static HttpClient httpClient;
    public readonly static string secret;
    static Globals()
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        secret = "";
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + secret);
    }
}
```

Just remember that there may be multiple instances of your function app running at the same time.  The static constructor will be called once per-application instance, and will be repeated any time your function app restarts.

Answer (score 1):

One more option could be with V2

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(InjectWebJobsStartup))]

namespace Startup
{
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            // Do init here
        }
    }
}
```

But since you need HttpClient, so maybe static class is better idea.